# The erlang observer of text

Tags: linux, erlang

I know the GUI tool for observing an Erlang system using `observer`.
I want to know that if there are tools  without GUI or with text?

Comment: https://github.com/zhongwencool/observer_cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use https://github.com/zhongwencool/observer_cli or https://github.com/ferd/recon. Or you can create your own text output info about the processes, system etc. use https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#process_info-1 and other internal functionality from the box of Erlang/OTP.